# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyName/MyRepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

I have an old Github account which works fine and I’ve recently created new Github account.in the new one whenever I’m trying to do git push command I get and error.the scenario is the two ones below and in both scenarios I get an error:

1. I initialize a local repo and then make a repo (without readme.md
   file) in my new github account and finally I try to push this local
   (initialized) repo to my new github account to my github repo.
2. I create a repo in my new Github account (with readme.md file) and
   cloning into my machine and after applying some changes and after
       doing git add and git commit I do the git push command but I got an
       error

Note: dolatabadiahmad is my new account and ahmaddolatabadi is my old account

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

remote: Permission to dolatabadiahmad/myone.git denied to ahmaddolatabadi.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dolatabadiahmad/myone.git/':

The requested URL returned error: 403.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636504/how-to-change-github-local-repo-git-config-credentials-to-circumvent-403/63647344#63647344.

Answer (score 0):

[You may not have more than one free GitHub Account.](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#b-account-terms)

Besides of that, you should look for your [Git Credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) to check whether the device has already recorded the username and password (since you are using HTTPS method) of your old account.

Comment: TNX @Geno Chen.

Answer (score 0):

account passwords way is not reliable,

better to use git in ssh way

> beginning November 13th, 2020, we will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating with the REST API and will require the use of token-based authentication (e.g., a personal access, OAuth, or GitHub App installation token) for all authenticated API operations on GitHub.com.

from [github blog](https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/)